# Imager Effects not working

Tags: plugins, image-transforms, plugin-imager

Usually the effects work fine for me, are there are server requirements to get them working that I have missed? or is the template code below incorrect?

```
{% for block in entry.clientLogos %}
    {% for image in block.clientLogo %}
        {% set logoImages = craft.imager.transformImage(image, 
        { width: 210, height: 90, mode: 'crop', position: 'center-center', jpegQuality: 90, effects: { grayscale: true, gamma: 1.5 } } 
        ) %}
        <img src="{{ image.url(logoImages) }}" alt="{{ block.clientTitle }}" title="{{ block.clientTitle }}"/>
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: What does "not working" mean? No image? One that 404s? Any related errors in browser's console and/or `craft/storage/runtime/logs`?

Comment: Hi Brad. No errors, the image appears transformed but without the effect. So image dimensions and cropping is working but not the effects.

Comment: Any errors on the log files?

Comment: Nothing that I can see.. The same snippet of template code works on another site perfectly..

Comment: Is the other site on the same box? If it's different, maybe it's a difference in imagick/GD between the boxes?